# Problem with Samesite in Google Login Popup

Tags: django, reactjs, google-chrome, google-oauth, samesite

In my project I use Google Login. This functionality stopped working few weeks ago. I run login with Google in iframe. It just closes the window and nothing happens. Inside dev tools there is the following warnings

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/
> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as
> Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are
> set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in
> developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details
> at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
>
> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://google.com/
> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as
> Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are
> set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in
> developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details
> at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
>
> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at
> https://accounts.google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.
> It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with
> cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.
> You can review cookies in developer tools under
> Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: I fixed the issue by refactoring my React code. But all warnings above still appears in dev console.

Comment: Here is the problem I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63703120/samesite-cookie-header-and-websocket-not-working any solutions advices?